# On mouse hover on label in registration page html tags are displaying in Joomla 3.2

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.2

I am facing strange issue with latest Joomla version. I am using `Joomla 3.2.1` and in my template when I go to sign up page and hover on the label of field so it shows html in tool tip, I have customized the `protostar` template. I don't know what is the issues with it. If some have any suggestion about that please let me know. Here the snapshot of that issues:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can't use code in that label field.  I'd say leave it at 'Enter your desired user name.' without the extra html code.  I'm not sure if you're using a plugin but you could always hack the plugin and set it to display how you need.